# rt_mutex_lock and mutex_lock in linux

Tags: c, linux-kernel, locking, mutex

I have read about `rt_mutex_lock`, which has priority inheritance for waiters.

- Apart from this what is difference between `rt_mutex` and `mutex` in Linux?
- In which case should we use `rt_mutex_lock`?